# jQuery how to add colour to div when selected

Tags: jquery

Hi I would like ask for help.

I have this jQuery script where the user must pick between the 2 buttons (man or woman).

My code wasn't flexible. If the one has been clicked and coloured, I can't get the button back to its normal colour when I picked the other one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.man-btn').on('click', function() {
        if($('.man-btn').hasClass('color')) {
            $('.man-btn').css('background', 'pink');
        }else
            $('.man-btn').css('background', '#25273e');
        };
    });

    $('.woman-btn').on('click', function() {
        if($('.woman-btn').hasClass('color')) {
            $('.woman-btn').css('background', 'pink');
        }else
            $('.man-btn').css('background', '#25273e');
        });
    });
});
```

Here's my html:

```
<div name="gender">
    <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
        <span>Man</span>
        <div class="man" >
            <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="woman-btn color" value="2">
        <span>Woman</span>
        <div class="woman">
            <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me! appreciate your help!

Comment: Using your Javascript, I'm getting a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 4):

Do it like below:-

***Example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.color').on('click', function() { // use the common class click event
    var gender = $.trim($(this).children('span').text());
    console.log(gender);
    $('.color').removeClass('pink');
    $(this).addClass('pink');
  });
});
```

```css
.pink{
 background :pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div name="gender">
  <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
    <span>Man</span>
    <div class="man" >
      <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="woman-btn color" value="2">
    <span>Woman</span>
    <div class="woman">
      <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gotcha! thank you so much for your help! Appreciated it so much!

Comment: btw, i've noticed that this code is not useful for my form. it was purely jquery practice.

Comment: i need to get the value for the buttons so I can proceed with the next step. It is part of form validation.

Comment: Alive to Die -- after I picked one of the button, I should get the value of it then the form should animate to the 2nd step.

Comment: @KobeBryan  ceck my latest edited answer. Now you will get the value in variable `gender` when you click the button

Comment: Alive to Die -- can we continue it to a chat? if it is okay with you?

Answer (score 3):

When you click the man button, change the class of both buttons, not just man.

When you click the woman button, change the class of both buttons, not just woman.

Use classes to change the colors. Remove one class, and add another.

Comment: can you show me sample pls? So I can have some basis

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler to toggle a class and put the style into a css rule:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $buttons = $('.man-btn, .woman-btn').on('click', function() {
    var $btn = $(this)
    $btn.toggleClass('color-pink', $btn.hasClass('color'));
     // remove from other one
     $buttons.not(this).removeClass('color-pink')
  });
});
```

```css
.color-pink {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="gender">
  <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
    <span>Man</span>
    <div class="man">
      <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="woman-btn color" value="2">
    <span>Woman</span>
    <div class="woman">
      <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sure is in my demo. If it's not working elsewhere then something is different

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.man-btn').on('click', function() {
            if($('.man-btn').hasClass('color')) {
                $('.man-btn').css('background', 'pink');
            }else{
                $('.man-btn').css('background', '#25273e');
            }
        });

        $('.woman-btn').on('click', function() {
            if($('.woman-btn').hasClass('color')) {
                $('.woman-btn').css('background', 'pink');
            }else{
                $('.man-btn').css('background', '#25273e');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div name="gender">
  <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
    <span>Man</span>
    <div class="man" >
      <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="woman-btn color" value="2">
    <span>Woman</span>
    <div class="woman">
      <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it appears you just copy/pasted his question.  Also, you didn't explain your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this greatly.  Just use one class as the button class (`gender`) and use a class to set the background color.  On click of any button, remove all instances of the class `gender`, then add the class to `$(this)`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".gender").on("click", function() {
  $(".pinkbg").removeClass("pinkbg");
  $(this).addClass("pinkbg");
 });
});
```

```css
.pinkbg {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="gender">
    <div class="gender man-btn color" value="1">
        <span>Man</span>
        <div class="man" >
            <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gender woman-btn color" value="2">
        <span>Woman</span>
        <div class="woman">
            <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/ma9hzLc1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.color').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).addClass('pink').siblings('.color').removeClass('pink');
  });
});
```

```css
.pink{
  background :pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="man-btn color" value="1">
  <span>Man</span>
  <div class="man" >
    <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="woman-btn color" value="2">
  <span>Woman</span>
  <div class="woman">
    <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```